# delete specific entries in table

Tags: c#, sql, database

In my table I have many rows with data.
One row has seven columns with values.

Is it possible to delete from one row values of two columns and rest five leave without changes?

Can I to it with SQL delete?

```
   cmd.CommandText = @"DELETE ImageData,"
                     + " ContentType,  "
                     + " FROM Users "
                     + " WHERE UserName = @UserName";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", username));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageData", ImageData));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContentType", ContentType));
```

In my code I can't delete like this, is it wrong?
Does anyone know how to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it's not `DELETE` you need but [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662(SQL.80).aspx).

- `DELETE` always removes an entire row.
- `UPDATE` allows you to change individual columns in a row.

**codefragment**

```
@"UPDATE Users "
  + "SET ContentType = NULL, "
  + "    ImageData = NULL "
  + "WHERE Username = @UserName";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `UPDATE` statement for this. `DELETE` is only for deleting whole row(s) at a time.

You can't actually "delete" them as though it was cells in a spreadsheet though. Assuming the columns are nullable you can set them to `NULL` as below.

```
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE ImageData
                    SET ContentType = NULL, Users = NULL
                    WHERE UserName = @UserName";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", username));
```

Comment: you mean so:  
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Users "
                                      + " SET ContentType =" + null + ", " + "ImageData =" + null + " " 
                                      + " WHERE UserName = @UserName ";  ???

Comment: @Ragmis See edit for C# version. If it doesn't work you need to give more details (does it give you an error message - If so what?)

Answer (score 1):

you could update the row:

```
UPDATE Users
SET ImageData = NULL, ContentType = NULL
WHERE UserName = @UserName
```